# Equality condition for relative entropy under partial trace

Tags: quantum-information, entropy

It is known that the relative entropy is non-increasing under arbitrary quantum operations. That is for some completely positive trace preserving map $N$, we have for all $\rho$ and $\sigma$

$$S(\rho ||\sigma) \geq S(N(\rho)||N(\sigma)).$$

Equality is achieved if there exists a recovery map that allows us to recover $\rho$ from $N(\rho)$ for all $\rho$. Now, consider the monotonicity of relative entropy under partial trace

$$S(\rho_{AB} ||\sigma_{AB}) \geq S(\rho_A ||\sigma_{A}).$$

Is there a general statement about $\rho_{AB}$ and $\sigma_{AB}$ if equality is achieved in this case?

Comment: What are your thoughts?

Comment: @NorbertSchuch I see this working only in the case of $\rho_{AB} = \rho_A\otimes \gamma_B$ and $\sigma_{AB} = \sigma_A \otimes \gamma_B$ i.e. they are separable states and the state in register $B$ is the same. I am unable to say anything more general than that.

Comment: What about e.g. |00>+|11> vs. |22>?

Comment: @NorbertSchuch Ok, so also when the spectrums of the two density operators are orthogonal it works. But apparently in this case there does not exist the "recovery" map mentioned in the question... So a statement "$S(\rho,\sigma)=S(N(\rho),N(\sigma))$ if and only if a map exists that allows us to recover $\rho$ from $N(\rho)$ for all $\rho$" is not true, if I get it right?

Comment: @Agnieszka *What* works? (Does it make sense to ask a new question?)